# Why does python hang when printing a list of strings?

Tags: python

I have been using python for some years now and this has never happened to me before. I'm placing the contents of a text file in a list. The file consists of 256 lines of numbers. Each line contains around 2000 characters. The following set of commands makes IDLE stop working:

```
>>> myFile = open(source_file)
>>> myList = myFile.readlines()
>>> print(myList[0])
(Correct Output)
>>> myList[0]
(Correct output)
>>> myList
(hangs, stops responding)
```

When I print one element of the list, the result is practically instantaneous, which is why I don't understand why printing all the elements at the same time makes IDLE hang.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget idle.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs - or is it just very slow?  The Tk text widget can get very slow when dealing with very long lines.

Comment: Indeed, it is not hanging, it's just line-wrapping a very big chunk of text. This is done in Python so it's not particularly fast.

Comment: Yes, not IDLE's strong suit, printing to the screen.

Comment: @kindall, the string is of a trivial size for Python processing - only half a megabyte.  You can see this for yourself by creating a list with 256 2000-character lines and displaying it with `pprint.pprint(thelist)` in IDLE.  Even 2000-character lines slow down the Tk text widget a lot, but it's still very much faster than waiting for Tk to format a 512Kb line.

Comment: Probably inaccurate to say python hangs. What's hanging here appears to be IDLE

Comment: I'd take Tim's advice over mine then.  :-)

Comment: Indeed this is an IDLE problem. When I try this as a file run on the command line, everything works as expected. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[comment converted to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731815/why-does-python-hang-when-printing-a-list-of-strings#comment61047306_36731815)</sub>

Python isn't hanging. IDLE is simply taking a long time to word wrap your text because the line is so long.